# Top margin added in android to button when it's text has multiple lines

Tags: android

I've encountered some strange behaviour.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi&#10;Hello"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this code adds top margin to button that has two lines of text in it or something else that pushes it down.

[image]

The only workaround I've found to make it look as expected

[image]

is to add negative top margin and smaller padding to the button with two lines of text

```
            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi&#10;Hello"/>
```

What causes that strange behaviour and how to handle it properly?

Comment: Set `baselineAligned="false"` on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Comment: It works. I have spend 2 hours to fix it unsuccesfully.

Comment: 2021, the right answer is still from @MikeM.: add android:baselineAligned="false" to the LinearLayout.